RSA encrypting private keys with blinding
Studying RSA, I stumbled upon a problem.
Alice encrypts the private factors ($p$ and $q$ from $n = p \cdot q$) of the modulus using her public key. In order to increase security, she multiplies them with a random integer $k$ (a process called blinding).
Namely, she performs the following operations: $
c_1 = (kp)^e \bmod n$ and $c_2 = (kq)^e \bmod n$.
We know $n$,$e$,$c_1$,$c_2$ and need to get the $d$ where $e \cdot d=1 \bmod e_\phi(n)$.
Simply dividing equations doesn't work in modular arithmetic $c_1 / c_2 = (p/q)^e \bmod n$, right?
Also getting $k^e \cdot p^e \bmod n = 
 k^e \bmod q = c_1$ and $k^e \bmod p = c_2$, how does it help to factorize $n$ here? It is said that $c_1$ or $c_2$ is enough to  factorize.

HINT: $p$ divides $c_1$; $q$ very likely does not.

@DanielS how did we get  that p divides c1 and does that mean gcd(c1,n) will give me the p?

Hint: for every strictly positive integers $u$ and $v$, with $w=u\ !v$, for all $x$ it holds $((x\bmod w)\bmod u)=(x\bmod u)$.

@fgrieu, so p divides c1, this does not help me to factorize n tho, c1 is a big number

@Metin: $p$ divides $c_1$, $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes , thus what can you say about $\gcd(c_1,n)$ when $0<c_1<n$, as that most likely stands?

@fgreiu gives the p, slipped my mind for some reason, thanks
